# It's giving me 0 as it should be 5 why is so

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl

### **It's giving me 0 as it should be 5 why is so.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<int> myvector{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto it = myvector.end();
    cout<<*it;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `end` __does not__ give you (an iterator to) the last element but one after the last.

Comment: If you need an iterator referring to the last element try [`rbegin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin) instead.

Comment: `*it` dereferences an `end()` iterator, so the behaviour is undefined.   Given only an end iterator, it is not generally possible to get back to the last element of a container.    Try `auto it = std::advance(myvector.begin(), myvector.size() - 1)`  (as long as `myvector.size()` is not zero - if it is zero, behaviour is undefined) or `auto it = myvector.rbegin()`  (which gives a different type of iterator).

Answer (score 0):

With all standard containers you should never dereference the end() iterator, never try to access the element that it points to. It is undefined behaviour and could abort the program.

In an old style loop you do something like the following code, as you can see if the iterator has value end() the loop will terminate.

```
for (auto it = myvector.begin(), it != myvector.end(), ++it)
   // do something with it
```

Since you have a vector replace end() with rbegin() or access directly to the last element with back().

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the last element of class “vector” you should call `back` method like: `myvector.back();`

And if you want to see the first element you should try `front` method: `myvector.front();`

For example:
`vector<int> myvector{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`

`myvector.back()` will give `5`

And
`myvector.front()` will give `1`.

To print out these values you fo not need to dereference your variable.

```
auto lastElement = myvector.back();
cout << lastElement;
```

That would print out number 5.

Answer (score 0):

access *it is undefined behavior. only [begin,end) can be accessed, The range is left close, right open.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    vector<int> myvector{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::cout << myvector[myvector.size()-1];
    return 0;
}
```

This way you can get the last element of the vector,and of course you can access the last element of the vector in many different ways.

Answer (score -2):

Try `myVector.end() - 1`.

`myVector.end()` is returning an iterator which points to past-the-end element in the vector.

Comment: there is no NULL in a vector. (and besides, this is a vector of int, not char).

Comment: Then you should fix your answer to avoid confusing future readers.

Comment: Incrementing or decrementing an end iterator from a standard container like `vector` gives undefined behaviour.